# glPointSize not changing point size

Tags: c, opengl, glut

The following code:

```
glPointSize(8);
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
  glColor3fv(yellow);
  glVertex2i(50, 50);
glEnd();
```

...produces a screen where the point is exactly one pixel big, like barely visible.

I've tried using:

```
glEnable(GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);
```

I've also tried to change the function to `GL_POINT` instead of `GL_POINTS` but that didn't even show a pixel

I've also tried to move around the different functions inside of the code like placing the color function outside `glBegin` and stuff like that, but to no avail.

And I have yet to find anyone on the internet with my exact problem, may it be problems with my hardware? (Debian 11 on Chromebook)

Comment: What's the value of [`GL_POINT_SIZE_RANGE`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGet.xhtml) on your GL implementation?  Make sure it's something other than [1.0, 1.0].  Also, edit in a [mcve].

Comment: This is an older version of OpenGL. What version are you using? Are you using shaders?

Comment: IIRC isn't `glEnable(GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);` meant for shaders? you are using old API there it should work without that statement (and using it might mess things up) also IIRC old GL specs was granted that only pixel sizes up to ~5 work and bigger might do god knows what on per PC basis. you use UNIX so it might be just bad GL implementation for your gfx try better or different gfx/GL driver